# Sympy: Using "assumptions" to evaluate Piecewise, specifically for IndexedBase

Tags: sympy, evaluation

I am trying to evaluate a certain expression under consideration of assumption. Specifically my problem is related to indexedBase objects.

See the following code:

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex="mathjax")


ntot = symbols("n_tot", integer = True)
i = Idx("i",(1,ntot))
k = Idx("k", (1,ntot))
j = Idx("j",(1,ntot))
x = IndexedBase("x")
```

As an example let's take the derivative of two summations over x[i].

```
expr = Sum(Sum(x[i],(i,1,ntot)),(k,1,ntot)).diff(x[j])
```

(**NOTE**: this is not possible in the current SymPy version 1.0, it is possible with the development version and will be available in future SymPy stable versions.)

I want to evaluate the expression and get a piecewise answer:

```
print(expr.doit())
OUTPUT: n_tot*Piecewise((1, And(1 <= j, j <= n_tot)), (0, True))
```

So my problem is, how can I tell sympy that I know for certain that j is between 1 and ntot. So that my result is 1:

I tried the following but with no luck:

```
with assuming(j==2):
     expr=Sum(Sum(x[i],(i,1,ntot)),(k,1,ntot)).diff(x[j]).doit()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions on inequalities are a sorely missed feature in SymPy.

Technically the `Idx` object was created to allow a symbol to contain a definition range, so as to put limits on indexed symbols. Your `j` already has this information:

```
In [28]: j.upper
Out[28]: n_tot

In [29]: j.lower
Out[29]: 1
```

Unfortunately, the inequality class is not meant to handle `Idx` objects, so its range gets disregared.

You could actually try:

```
In [32]: simplify(expr.doit()).args[0][0]
Out[32]: n_tot
```

This manually extracts the first term of the `Piecewise` expression.

Obviously, the current algorithm needs improvement, it should already tell to `Sum` that `j` is within the correct range in order to give 1 as a result.

Comment: Thank you Francesco. At least I know that it is currently not possible and can proceed. Thx.